# Failure loading image / flutter

Tags: image, flutter

After loading photo in my apps, I receive error message below which I do not understand what it means.

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6937): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
I/ExifInterface_JNI( 6937): Raw image not detected
I/ExifInterface_JNI( 6937): Raw image not detected
D/EGL_emulation( 6937): eglCreateContext: 0xaca058a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 6937): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaca058a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaca03410)
E/eglCodecCommon( 6937): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon( 6937): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon( 6937): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000087fe
D/EGL_emulation( 6937): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa837d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa8351530)
D/EGL_emulation( 6937): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaca058a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaca03410)
```

I do not see the connection between the failure the different input I have related to saving images.
My app is working by showing the image.

```
           SizedBox(height: 16),
            _imageFile == null && _imageUrl == null
                ? ButtonTheme(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _getLocalImage();
                        loading = true;
                        },
                        child: Text(
                        'Add Image',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

```
  _getLocalImage() async {
    File imageFile =
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50, maxWidth: 400);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = imageFile;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Need more source to show image using '_imageFile' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the 'loading = true;' I working on replacing to Loading Builder to indicate loading view of the photo.